# Import a specific sheet in an Excel file into Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

How can I import a specific sheet in an Excel file into Matlab (as an array or table)?

Apparently `xlsread` is [not recommended](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html?s_tid=doc_ta#btg5vmt-1-sheet) in the official documentation. However, their recommended method of `readtable` does not allow you specify a sheet name (I think? perhaps missed it?)

Using `test = xlsread('myfile.xlsx', 'my sheet name')` seems to work fine in my case, except it skips column headers. Is there a way to keep headers?

Using `test = readtable('myfile.xlsx')` keeps the headers but just automatically imports the first sheet.

On Windows, Matlab R2018a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `readtable` reads the first sheet. You can specify sheet number/name as well to read your desired sheet.

```
test = readtable('myfile.xlsx','Sheet','my sheet name');
```

Please read the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html#d123e1138129) for more details.